# Rolling sum filling intermediate values on grouped DataFrames

Tags: pandas

I'm migrating one of my Spark project to Pandas now, and one of the problems I met is to implement a rolling-sum like function in pandas within each group.

Suppose I have:

```
key time value
A   1    10
A   2    20
A   4    30
A   8    10
B   1    15
B   2    30
B   3    15
```

I want to first group by `key`, then calculate a rolling-sum like function that fills intermediate time slots on `value` with respect to `time`. For example, if window size is 2, my desired output will be:

```
key time output
A   1    10    
A   2    30 (10+20)    
A   3    30 (10+20+0)
A   4    50 (20+0+30) 
A   5    30 (0+30+0)
A   6    30 (the same as above)
A   8    10 (7 is 0 so it is omitted)
A   9    10
A   10   10
B   1    15
B   2    45
B   3    60
B   4    45
B   5    15
```

I have struggled on `group by` and `apply` for a whole afternoon. Is there a clever way to do this? In spark I can `collect_list` then `select` an udf to `time` and `value` to do this, but pandas seems to think differently than Spark.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be "creating" data. It isn't clear how the output has time from  1 to 5 for A and only 1 to 4 for B.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Sorry for being unclear, the last value of record lasts for 1 time slot because the window size is 1.

Comment: is your result for window size 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

IIUIC, here's one approach.

First create `dff` with new time windows

```
In [1458]: dff = (df.groupby('key')
                    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x.time.min(), x.time.max()+2)))
                    .reset_index(name='time').drop('level_1', 1))
In [1459]: dff
Out[1459]:
  key  time
0   A     1
1   A     2
2   A     3
3   A     4
4   A     5
5   B     1
6   B     2
7   B     3
8   B     4
```

Then, merge on earlier `df`, groupby on `key`, add current and previous `value` using `shift`

```
In [1460]: dff.assign(ouput=dff.merge(df, how='left')
                               .fillna(0).groupby('key').value
                               .apply(lambda x: x+x.shift().fillna(0)))
Out[1460]:
  key  time  ouput
0   A     1   10.0
1   A     2   30.0
2   A     3   20.0
3   A     4   30.0
4   A     5   30.0
5   B     1   15.0
6   B     2   45.0
7   B     3   45.0
8   B     4   15.0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wonder if there are two problems with this approach: first, it generates consecutive time slots from time.min to time.max, if the time is `1, 2, 8, 16`, there will be lots of wasted slots generated. Second, `shift` only applies when window size is 1, but it is not always the case...

Comment: I changed the sample data in the question description now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to generate the whole range of `time` in a certain group and then do a `dropna` afterwards

```
def make_rolling_sum(key, group, window):
    time_range = range(group['time'].min(), group['time'].max() + 1 + window, )
    df = group.set_index('time').reindex(time_range)
    result = df.rolling(window, min_periods=1).sum()
    result['key'] = key  # the reindex drops a lot of NaN's in this column
    return result.dropna().reset_index().reindex(columns=group.columns)

window = 3
pd.concat((make_rolling_sum(*group, window)for group in df.groupby('key')), ignore_index=True)
```

yields

```
    key     time    value
0   A   1   10.0
1   A   2   30.0
2   A   3   30.0
3   A   4   50.0
4   A   5   30.0
5   A   6   30.0
6   A   8   10.0
7   A   9   10.0
8   A   10  10.0
9   B   1   15.0
10  B   2   45.0
11  B   3   60.0
12  B   4   45.0
13  B   5   15.0
```